# Can't install "Docky" theme?

Tags: ubuntu, themes, docky

So to install a theme for Docky on Ubuntu I had to extract the theme from the Archive Manager via root to /usr/local/share/docky/themes. I did this but it didn't show up in the theme choices. Then I tried just pressing the install button and locating it but I couldn't see the tar file. I then extracted the tar file to the desktop and tried selecting that to install but nothing. What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: What theme are you trying to install?

Comment: Elegant, the one that looks like Mac OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to restart Docky for a theme extracted to `~/.local/share/docky/themes` or `/usr/share/docky/themes` to appear in the list.

Double-check the above directory and make sure there is a directory called `Elegant` with 5 `.svg` files inside. Then press ALT+F2, type in `pkill docky`, and press Enter.  Docky will exit.  Now press ALT+F2 again and type `docky` and press Enter.  Docky will reappear.

The *Elegant* theme should now appear appear in the *Theme* dropdown when you click the blue anchor icon on the left side of Docky.

Comment: http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lhs5k4TUOx1qboy47o1_500.png I did EVERYTHING you said and it still did not show up. What is wrong!?

Comment: @Earl The only thing I did differently is install it in my home directory, not /usr/, but that *should* work.  I'll try it that way and see if it works.

Comment: @Earl:  You need to put it in `/usr/share/docky/themes/` not `/usr/local/share/docky/themes`.  Since Ubuntu offers Docky in its repositories it doesn't put it in the `/usr/local` folder.

Comment: Thanks so much! They didn't give the directions correctly on the actual themes site... This was absolutely fantastic!